# Django Rest Framework: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, cors

SOLUTION: Add a trailing slash to the end of the url...

"http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc/" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc"

....

I have successfully created a Django Rest API and am able to store and host data locally it seems. I have built an angularjs1.0 app separately and am attempting to extract the data via $http get request however I'm running into this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.20.9.163:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have attempted to install CORS and have added it to my INSTALLED_APPS, yet nothing seems to be working yet.

This is the get request:

```
getABC : function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc',
                cache: false
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                callback(data);
            });
        },
```

Here's a look at my Django settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'xyz',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: Can you open the Network tab in Dev tools and check the response to your AJAX request? Does it actually contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: Sorry, where should I be seeing this? I've got the network tab open but I don't see an ajax request response anywhere.

Comment: @IgorRaush "Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 MOVED PERMANENTLY (from cache)" 

And when clicking the "response" tab it says "This request has no response data available."

Comment: Something is off. Your API is returning a redirect response. Is there a `Location` header on that response? Can you run `curl --head http://localhost:8000/xyz/api/abc` from the command line?

Comment: Also, it appears that the request may not even reach the server, it is cached in the browser as a `301 Moved Permanently`...

Comment: I did and I got:

HTTP/1.0 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 19:12:48 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.1
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93532/discussion-between-tryingtolearn-and-igor-raush).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Issue your AJAX request to a slash-appended URL.

**Explanation**

After our discussion, it appears that the culprit is Django's automatic `APPEND_SLASH = True` which is enabled when `CommonMiddleware` is enabled.

This causes the AJAX request from your Angular app to first hit a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect to the slash-appended URL. However, the `corsheaders` middleware does not act on this response, so the browser complains about a missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

This is solved by requesting the slash-appended URL directly, and bypassing the 301 redirect altogether.

```js
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc/',  // trailing slash here
    cache: false
}).success(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Install django-crops-headers

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

> In setting.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
             #...
                 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
                 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
             ]
INSTALLED_APPS = [

                'corsheaders',
                 #...
                ]
```

> Set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL is True

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # this allows all domains

Or to allow specific domains 

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'http://example.com',
'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
'http://localhost:8000',
 )
```

> In Ajax call(front end) add headers:

```
 var get_request = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  "headers": {
          "accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
      },
  url: 'http://example.com',
});
```

> If it is not solved, You should enable the core in requesting server(http://example.com)