# Django Vue Js Axios has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, cors

Im using Django as backend and Vue as frontend, i use axios to make a request from Vue to Django.

I know there is so many question about this, i've tried it all and wouldn't post a question if im not, i have been Googling it about 4 hours and yet still have the blocked by cors policy.
[image: blocked by cors policy]

I've tried:

- Django-cors-header, with its middleware
- Vue-axios-cors, got new error with this one
- Adding header Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
- Adding / at the end of the url

When i inspect it using fiddler, the POST request become OPTIONS, i have no idea whats happening.

main.js

```
import Axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$http = Axios

const csrf = localStorage.getItem("csrftoken")

if (csrf){
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrf
}

Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, access-control-allow-origin, Authorization"
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
```

Login.vue

```
login(){

  const header = {
    headers:{
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*",
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, access-control-allow-origin, Authorization",
     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : "true",
    }
  }

  this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/login/',{
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,

  },header).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
  })

},
```

this are the response from the network tab
[image]

settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',

    'dashboard',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vue'),
    ]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the excepted URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/login/` with the leading slash? It might cause some problems:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375797/django-rest-framework-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-127-0-0-18000-xyz-api. Also, what is the value of `APPEND_SLASH` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @O-9 , yes i did, i've tried it with and without slash, still got the same result.
i did not have APPEND_SLASH variable in settings.py.

and from that link, i think its different from my problem cause i got response header in the network tab

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login

Comment: @O-9 the response header screenshot is in the post, i've updated it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different port is considered a different domain for CORS, use https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware and set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` in your settings

Remove setting the headers in Vue, the default headers will work. You are only making CORS requests from Vue to Django, not from Django to Vue. You would only need to set these headers if you were making CORS requests from another domain to Vue.

Comment: Allowing all origins is a great security risk.

Comment: @AbdRahmanAlkaff Try removing all the headers from the Vue side they shouldn't be required (other than the csrf)

Comment: @Rehmat It is a security risk, but it is up to the OP to decide that. For development and learning it is not necessary.

Comment: @Rehmat  thanks for the advise, i'll make sure to do that once i deploy it. but i think that wouldnt solve my problem with Api request blocked by CORS. how do i fix it? i've tried it all lol, i've been googling for days, is it a bug?

Comment: @Airith the Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?, can i know why? because i've read somewhere that it is required for CORS

Comment: It should send the correct headers by default, try without them first.

Comment: @Airith oh my, how, it worked!, i dont understand why, but it does, blocked by CORS is no more.

Comment: Updated this answer with the explanation.